# Unhandled promise rejection Android with React-native Error code: E_MISSING_PERMISSION

Tags: android, react-native

screenshot of error (same on device and emulator):
[image: screenshot of error (same on device and emulator)]:

> console.error: "Unhandled promise rejection", {"framesToPop":1,"code":"E_MISSING_PERMISSION","line":68885,"column":29."sourceURL":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false"}

I have been developing with the iOS emulator, so launches fine with that, but now having troubles getting it to run on Android.

I have no idea what file is being referred to by the error so have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. One of the modules react-native-blur wasn't fully installed as android requires an extra step modifying the build.gradle file.

Comment: What would that extra step be?

Answer (score 0):

As seen here: https://github.com/dabit3/appsync-graphql-cities/issues/3
I fixed this by navigating to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android 
    -> app 
        -> src 
            -> main 
                -> AndroidManifest.xml
```

then add the line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`